# Read text file in angular line by line

Tags: angular

I have this text file:

`"u901_humext  ""2019-02-10 00:00""    99.97   99.97   99.97"`

`"u901_radpar   ""2019-02-10 15:40""    1002.9  1068.4  1034.3943396226"`

And I want to take the data from the line like:

`name = u901_humext date = 2019-02-10 00:00 min = 99.97 avg = 99.97 max = 99.97`

I have this class with the function but only can display all the data:

```js
    export class LeerArchivoComponent implements OnInit {
      private fileText;
      private nombre:String;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      fileUpload(event){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(event.srcElement.files[0]);
        var me = this;
        var nombre:String;
        reader.onload = function (){
          me.fileText = reader.result;     

        }
      }
```

And the html like:

```html
    <input id="file-upload" 
      type="file" 
      accept=".txt" 
      (change)="fileUpload($event)">     
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">{{fileText}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the ArrayBuffer to string, After try to split your text by lines like:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

const text = ab2str(reader.result);
const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Afterwards you can split every line by a space to read every individual value:

```
lines.forEach(line => {
   const vars = line.split(' ');
   console.log(vars);
});
```

[ab2str source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String)

Comment: The problem is that reader.result is a ArrayBuffer and ArrayBuffer doesnt have split function.

Comment: You can convert it to string. I have updated the answer.